Proving quasi-concavity for a utility function
I have a utility function, and I want to prove that it is a quasi-concave function:
$$ u(x_1,x_2)= 2x_1x_2+x_1+2x_2 $$
I do this by showing that the set of points where the utility is larger than or equal to any given level forms a convex set, and denote this level of utility by $U^{x}$ The set of points where the utility function is larger than or equal to can be represented as:
$$ S ={ (x_1,x_2)|2x_1x_2+x_1+2x_2 ≥ u^{x}} $$
So I have to prove that the set S is convex for all possible values $u^{x}$
I consider two arbitrary points ($x_1^{a},x_2^{a}$) and ($x_1^{b},x_2^{b}$) in the set S that satisfy:
$$[2x_1^{a}x_2^{a}+x_1^{a}+2x_2^{a} ≥ u^{x} ]$$
$$[2x_1^{b}x_2^{b}+x_1^{b}+2x_2^{b} ≥ u^{x} ]$$
Now, if I take a convex combination of those points:
$$(x_1,x_2)= \lambda(x_1^{a},x_2^{a})+(1-\lambda)(x_1^{b},x_2^{b}$$ where $(0≤\lambda≤1)$. This lies within the line segment connecting ($x_1^{a},x_2^{a}$) and ($x_1^{b},x_2^{b}$)
Now I evaluate the utility function at the point $(x_1,x_2)$:
$$u(x_1,x_2)= 2x_1x_2+x_1+2x_2$$
I now substitute the expression for $(x_1,x_2)$:
$$u(x_1,x_2)= 2 (\lambda x_1^{a}+(1-\lambda)(x_1^{b})(\lambda x_2^{a}+(1-\lambda)(x_2^{b}))) + \lambda x_1^{a}+(1-\lambda)(x_1^{b} + 2 \lambda x_2^{a}+(1-\lambda)(x_2^{b})) $$
I know that I now have to show that u(x_1,x_2) is larger than or equal to $u^{x}$, but I am not sure how to proceed further. I would greatly appreciate any help.
EDIT: Solved!

For quasi-concavity, you have to show that the set of points where the utility is larger or equal (!) to a certain level is convex.

Thank you, I have updated my answer.

Something to consider is that you have three (!) more left parentheses in your final equation than right parentheses. Now I am a man of left wing leanings, but this seems too radical even to me.

If you solved it, you can post an answer to your own question. Other readers might be interested.

Consider the upper level set
\begin{eqnarray*}S_a&=&\left\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+|2x_1x_2+x_1+2x_2\geq a\right\}\\ &=& \left\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+|2(x_1+1)\left(x_2+\frac{1}{2}\right)\geq a+1\right\}\\ &=& \left\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+|(x_1+1)\left(x_2+\frac{1}{2}\right)\geq \dfrac{a+1}{2}\right\}\\ &=& \left\{(u,v)-\left(1,\frac{1}{2}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+|uv\geq \dfrac{a+1}{2}\right\} \\ &=& \left\{(u,v)\in[1,\infty)\times[\frac{1}{2},\infty)|uv\geq \dfrac{a+1}{2}\right\} -\left(1,\frac{1}{2}\right) \ \ \ [\text{Element-wise subtraction}]\end{eqnarray*}
which is a convex set if and only if
$$\left\{(u,v)\in[1,\infty)\times[\frac{1}{2},\infty)|uv\geq \dfrac{a+1}{2}\right\}=\left\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+|uv\geq \dfrac{a+1}{2}\right\}\bigcap [1,\infty)\times[\frac{1}{2},\infty)$$ is a convex set.
So, it is sufficient to show
$T_k=\left\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+|uv\geq k\right\}$
is a convex set for all $k\in\mathbb{R}$.
We'll now show that.
For $k\leq 0$, $T_k=\left\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+|uv\geq k\right\}=\mathbb{R}^2_+$ is a convex set.
Now consider for any $k>0$, the set
$T_k=\left\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+|uv\geq k\right\}$. To show that $T_k$ is convex, consider any $(u',v')\in T_k$ and $(u'',v'')\in T_k$, and any $\lambda\in (0,1)$, we'll show that $(\lambda u'+(1-\lambda)u'', \lambda v'+(1-\lambda)v'')\in T_k$
To show this, we'll need the following inequality:
Without loss of generality letting $k\leq u'v'\leq u''v''$, the following holds:
$u'v''+u''v'=u'v'(\frac{v''}{v'}+\frac{u''}{u'})\geq u'v'(\frac{u'}{u''}+\frac{u''}{u'})\geq 2k$
[Please note that $(\frac{u'}{u''}+\frac{u''}{u'})\geq 2$ because $\min_{a>0} a + \frac{1}{a} = 2$]
Therefore, we also have $u'v''+u''v'\geq 2k$ along with $u'v'\geq k$, $u''v''\geq k$.
Now, we'll show that $(\lambda u'+(1-\lambda)u'', \lambda v'+(1-\lambda)v'')\in T_k$. Here is the argument:
\begin{eqnarray*}
&& (\lambda u'+(1-\lambda)u'')(\lambda v'+(1-\lambda)v'') \\ &=&
\lambda^2 u'v'+ \lambda(1-\lambda)(u'v''+u''v')+ (1-\lambda)^2u''v''\\ &\geq & \lambda^2 k+ \lambda(1-\lambda)(2k)+ (1-\lambda)^2k \\ &=& (\lambda^2 + 2\lambda(1-\lambda)+ (1-\lambda)^2)k \\ &=& k
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $(\lambda u'+(1-\lambda)u'', \lambda v'+(1-\lambda)v'')\in T_k$.
So, $T_k=\left\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+|uv\geq k\right\}$
is a convex set for all $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

Alternatively, you could check the bordered hessian:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_1} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2}\\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2 \partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant of this matrix is strictly positive for $x_1, x_2 > 0$, which shows the function is quasi-concave on $\mathbb{R}^2_{++}$.
